# Overflow button does not work twice when a button group is among the components in the overflow

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, toolbar, buttongroup, overflow-menu

Looked up to find a similar issue in the forum.

[Overflow button does not work twice when a button group is among the components in the overflow.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175280-4.1-beta-and-4.0.7-bug-Overflow-button-does-not-work-twice)

**Is this fixed yet ?**

My code snippet for the toolbar looks like this :

```
           {
                id: 'mypanel',
                xtype: 'panel',
                autoScroll: true,
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                dockedItems:[{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top',
                    enableOverflow: true,
                    items:[
                        {

                            xtype: 'buttongroup',
                            region: 'north',
                           // minHeight: 50,
                            //autoScroll: true,
                            items:  getButtons4()
                        },
                        {

                            xtype: 'buttongroup',
                            region: 'north',
                           // minHeight: 70,
                            //autoScroll: true,
                            items:  getButtons3()
                        },
                        {

                            xtype: 'buttongroup',
                            region: 'north',
                            //minHeight: 70,
                            //autoScroll: true,
                            items:  getButtons1()
                        },
                        {

                            xtype: 'buttongroup',
                            region: 'north',
                            //minHeight: 70,
                            //autoScroll: true,
                            items:  getButtons2()
                        },
                        {

                            xtype: 'buttongroup',
                            region: 'north',
                            title: 'Others',
                            //minHeight: 70,
                            //autoScroll: true,
                            items:  getOtherButtons()
                        }
                    ]
                }],
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'tabpanel',
                        id: 'mytabpanel',
                        activeTab: 0,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        region: 'center',
                        disabled: 'true',
                        items:[
                            {

                                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                height : '80%',
                                width : '100%'
                            },
                            {

                                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                height : '80%',
                                width : '100%'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your following code:

`enableOverflow: true`

with my following code:

`layout: {overflowHandler: 'Menu'}`